# How to expose Project Module Library to App Module (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

At first, I am using a single module `app` for the the Android Application, but now I want to separate the module into `app` module (core-business logic and UI) and `libraries` module (HTTP-related and base abstract classes).

I made new `libraries` module as the library module and start moving some utility code from `app` to `libraries` but problem comes. The problem is, I want my `app` to use the dependency used in `libraries` module without having to include same dependency in both build.gradle.

In my `app` module, I want my source code to use the `RecyclerView` and `Retrofit` defined in `libraries`, but I can't do it unless I also include `retrofit` and `recyclerview-v7` in my app/build.gradle.

app/main/src/..../HomeActivity.kt

```
var gridDataset: RecyclerView? = null // RecyclerView not found in classpath
```

app/build.gradle

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation project(":libraries")
```

libraries/build.gradle

```
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_library_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0"
```

Where did I go wrong? Or is it simply impossible to do that?

Comment: maybe use `api project(":libraries")` instead of `implementation project(":libraries")`

Comment: No, I've tried that too and that doesn't solve

Answer (score 0):

specify your dependencies in libraries/build.gradle using api instead of implementation

This should add these dependencies to the class path for any module depending on your libraries module

```
api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_library_version"
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0"
api "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0"
```